# Integrating $\int_{0}^{x} e^{ie^{\frac{s}{2}}}ds$

Tags: calculus, integration, heat-equation, change-of-variable

How would one proceed to evaluate $\int_{0}^{x} e^{ie^{\frac{s}{2}}}ds$? I was considering a change of variables $p=\sqrt{-i}e^{\frac{s}{4}}$, so that I could express the function in terms of $\mathscr{Erf}$, though the expansion for $ds$ would not be tidy.

Comment: The limit and the integration variable are the same. Where did you get this integral?

Comment: I've updated the dummy variable to $s$. Thank you.

Comment: Make the substitution $u = e^{s/2}$. Looks like you'll end up with a $E_1$ or $\text{Ei}$. https://dlmf.nist.gov/6

Comment: @Andrei, I found the integral by generating a system of odes from $\left(2\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + ie^{\frac{x}{2}}\right)\left(2\frac{\partial}{\partial x} - ie^{\frac{x}{2}}\right) v(x)=0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$$
e^{ie^{t/2}}=\sum^\infty_{n=0}(i)^ne^{nt/2}/n!
$$

Exchange order of integration and summation (this need some justification, but this is valid here)
$$
\int^x_0e^{ie^{t/2}}\,dt=\int^x_0\Big(\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{i^n}{n!}e^{nt/2}\Big)\,dt=\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{i^n}{n!}\int^x_0e^{nt/2}\,dt
$$

Can you finish from here?

Comment: Is there any closed-form solution?

Comment: I don't thinks so.  Liouville's theorem on existence of antiderivatives could be a way to prove that there is no "elementary" way to express that integral in terms of nice functions. In any event, having a series representation that converges fast is not too bad.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any suggestions for reading material on this subject?

Comment: I don't have a specific reference fo differentiable fields theory. Google Liouville's differentiability theorem for a start. That topic requires some knowledge of Field extensions. Read about this after you are comfortable with basic abstract algebra.

Comment: I am interested in reading about abstract algebra. Do you have a favorite textbook? I actually was going to place the result from this integral into a power series. Do you have ideas about how to consider convergence properties with double summations? Thank you for all of your insight. (Thankfully, they aren't being multiplied, so I won't have to take a Cauchy product.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122917/discussion-between-jpwin-and-oliver-diaz).