# Solving $v'(x) - ie^{x/2} v(x) = e^{2ie^{x/2}}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, complex-numbers, complex-integration, integrating-factor

While considering the first order inhomogenous ODE
$$
v'(x) - ie^{x/2} v(x) = e^{2ie^{x/2}},
$$
I became curious about the most concise way to produce a solution. For the homogenous equation $$v_h'(x)-ie^{x/2}v_h(x) = 0$$ that I will use to satisfy the boundary conditions, I employed a separation of variables to determine $v_h(x) = Ce^{2ie^{x/2}}$. For a particular solution $v_p(x)$ of the inhomogeneous equation, I had thought about employing a method of integrating factors, though I noticed such a method worked well only for particular coefficients. I feel as though a variation of parameters or Laplace transform would be far too much for the problem. Does anyone have simple method for solving the above equation?

Thank you all.

Comment: Looks like integrating factor will work here, why do you suspect it won't?

Comment: Thank you. If you post that as an answer, I'll accept it. I had simply wondered if anyone else had a more concise solution.

Answer (score 2):

We take
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \left(e^{-2ie^{x/2}}v(x)\right) = v'(x)e^{-2ie^{x/2}} -i e^{-2ie^{x/2}} v(x)=e^{2ie^{x/2}}.
$$
Although the resulting formula is not particular nice, we conclude as follows.

$$v_p(x) = \exp\left(2ie^{x/2}\right)
           \int_0^x \exp\left(2i e^{s/2}\right) ds$$

For a method to evaluate this integral, please refer to the following [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4099696/integrating-int-0x-eie-fracs2ds).

Answer (score 0):

For the homogeneous equation, you found
$$v=C \,e^{2 i e^{x/2}}$$ Variation of the parameter gives
$$C'=1 \implies C=x + k \implies v= ???$$